# coverage reduced when using defaultProps in react-scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-scripts

I'm using the latest version of react-scripts and when I'm trying to add default props for a method then the coverage gets reduced.

Project

```
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {onClick} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <button
            className="App-link"
            onClick={onClick}
          >
            Learn React
          </button>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func
}

App.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {}
}
```

New Coverage
[image]

Comment: Did you add a unit test case to cover it clicking the button when a callback isn't passed to the component?

Comment: This is the only test I have:
```
it('Should click button', () => {
  const onClick = jest.fn();
  const component = shallow(<App onClick={onClick} />);
  component.find('.App-link').simulate('click');
  expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
});
```
what type of test do you mean? so everytime I add defaultProps I need to tests de defaultProps with Jest?

Comment: No, but if you're looking to get that 100% coverage you can write a test that doesn't pass an `onClick` prop, search for the button text, and simulate a click. This isn't a very compelling test though, as it isn't really testing *your* code, but rather it is testing that react sets default prop values. It's about where I would start with a "renders and doesn't crash". I think in general if your coverage is at least 80% then you're in a good spot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Drew. I do have a test like that with react-test-renderer and snapshot, but still the coverage doesn’t increase. I think that in this case the best would be to exclude default props from the coverage report

Answer (score 0):

as @Drew Reese mentioned the solution would be just to simulate the onClick without passing the onClick prop.

```
test("default prop for onClick", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<SearchBox />);
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId("whatever"));
});
```